# std::is_constant_evaluated() and const variables

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

Let's consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

int foo(int arg) {
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}  

int main() {
    const auto b = foo(0);
    return b;
}
```

It returns 0 with both [gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/bd33ss). I would have expected it to return 1 instead.

If `foo()` is made `constexpr`, while `b` is kept simply `const`, then it does return 1.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: How can it return 1 instead? If a function is not declared `constexpr` it cannot be part of constant evaluation.

Comment: `const` does not imply that the value must be known at compile time, in case thats the misunderstanding

Comment: All non-constexpr calls happen at run time.  Only `constexpr` or `consteval` function run at compile time.  That's why they were introduced.

Comment: and why you expect it to return 1? it's l-value that isn't evaluated

Comment: Because the generated assembly code shows that the function has been optimized out, hence "called" at compile-time. After reading the proposal P0595R2, there is a distinction between "compile time" and "constant evaluated context". I believe my example is like the "call (3)" described in the section "Introduction and Motivation".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::is_constant_evaluated()` returns true if and only if [[meta.const.eval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.const.eval):

> evaluation of the call occurs within the evaluation of an expression or conversion that is manifestly constant-evaluated

This term, "manifestly constant-evaluated" (defined [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#def:manifestly_constant-evaluated)), refers to contexts that have to be constant-evaluated. A call to a non-`constexpr` function (the nearest enclosing context here) is *never* constant evaluated, because it's non-`constexpr`, so this is straight-forwardly not "manifestly constant-evaluated."

Once we make it `constexpr` though, we're in this weird legacy quirk. Before C++11, which introduced `constexpr`, we could still do stuff like this:

```cpp
template <int I> void f();

const int i = 42; // const, not constexpr
f<i>();           // ok
```

Basically, we have this carve out for *specifically* integral (and enumeration) types declared const that are initialized with a constant expression. Those still count as constant expressions.

So this:

```cpp
const auto b = foo(0);
```

If `foo(0)` is an integral constant expression, then `b` is something that could be used as a compile time constant (and would be constant-initialized<sup>†</sup>, if it were at namespace scope). So what happens here is we do a two-step parse. We first try to evaluate `foo(0)` as if it were a constant expression and then, if that fails, fall back to *not* doing that.

In this first parse, with `foo(0)` evaluated as a constant, `is_constant_evaluated()` is (by definition) `true`, so we get `1`. This parse succeeds, so we end up with `b` as a compile-time constant.

---

<sup>†</sup>For namespace-scope variables, constant-initialization is an important concept as well - to avoid the static initialization order fiasco. It leads to other gnarly examples (see [P0595](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0595r2.html)).

The important thing here is basically: `is_constant_evaluated()` should only be switched on to select a compile-time-safe algorithm vs a runtime algorithm, not to actually affect the semantics of the result.

Answer (score 6):

You have to be a little careful with where and how you use `is_constant_evaluated`. There are 3 kinds of functions in C++, and `is_constant_evaluated` only makes sense in one of them.

```
// a strictly run-time function
int foo(int arg) 
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated()) // pointless: always false
        // ...
}

// a strictly compile time function
consteval int foo(int arg) 
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())  // pointless: always true
        // ...
}

// both run-time and compile-time
constexpr int foo(int arg) 
{
    if (std::is_constant_evaluated())  // ok: depends on context in 
                                       // which `foo` is evaluated
        // ...
}
```

Another common mistake worth pointing out is that `is_constant_evaluated` doesn't make any sense in an `if constexpr` condition either:

```
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constant_evaluated()) // pointless: always true
                                                // regardless of whether foo 
                                                // is run-time or compile-time
}
```